# Dictionary out of strings with blanks as the key/value separator

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I have a text file that looks like this:

A    (four spaces) 16

B (four spaces) 25

etc.

I need to make a dictionary that looks like this: dic = { A:16, B:25, etc.}
I have already tried "split" (which turned out doesn't work with spaces). 
Here is my code so far:

```
lines = []
with open("ABC.txt","r") as filein:
    for line in filein:
        lines.append(line.strip('\n'))
print lines
```

which for the moment gives me a list of strings : "A(four spaces)16", "B(fourspaces)25") etc. I just need to separate the key from value using the four spaces as a cutoff.
Any advice?

Comment: `str.split()` works *great* with spaces. What exactly did you try and what happened? For your input string `'A    16\n'.split()` produces `['A', '16']` for example.

Comment: You're calling `strip`, not `split`...

Comment: Yes, I called strip to read my file in which letter-value couples were each on a new line.

Comment: I just tried with split() instead of split("    ") and it worked! Thank you very much Martijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why `split` shouldn't work... Try the following.

```
dic = {}
with open("ABC.txt",'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        key,value = l.split() #Set two temporary variables for easy access to data
        dic[key] = int(value) #Set the appropriate key of the list to its respective value
print dic
```

Comment: probably should just use `l.split()` instead of `l.split(' ')`.  The former splits on consecutive runs of any whitespace which OP apparently has.

Comment: And now change `l = l.split()` to `key, val = l.split()`. (also in the next step). Much nicer.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor `dict()` takes an iterable of key-value pairs.  So the dictionary can be built directly like so:

```
with open("ABC.txt","r") as filein:
    mydict = dict(line.split() for line in filein)
```

Comment: I personally think this is a better solution.

Comment: And so do the others who upvoted it, @Gareth. :-) That's why stackoverflow doesn't just rely on the OP to choose the best answer.

Answer (score -2):

lines is not a dictionary it is a list to make it a dictionary you should initilize:

```
lines = {}
```

You could also do:

```
 for line in filein:
     lines[line[0]] = line[-2:]
```

assuming the length of your keys and values is always the same and also assuming one line is somethin like

```
      A    25
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, my keys and values are varying in length towards the end of the list... I solved the problem by using split(). It turns out I have been using it incorrectly and this is why my code didn't work!

Comment: Could somebody tell me why my answer was downvoted? It should certainly work for the specified case.

Comment: It actually doesn't work.  line[:-2] takes everything up to the last few 2 characters send you end up with  `In [2]: line[0], line[:-2]
Out[2]: ('A', 'A    ') `.  Also, it doesn't account for numbers that are more or less than 2 digits, or keys that are more than one digit

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I had the : on the wrong side of the number. as for keys with more than one and numbers with not exactly 2 digits, yes, it does not work in those cases, but I already mentioned that in the original answer.